# MqTT connection issue Uno R4 Wifi

Tags: wifi, alexa-skills-kit, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make an Alexa controlled button presser with a servon to actuate the button. I'm using a Uno R4 Wifi and I'm running into this error:

> ArduinoIoTCloudTCP::handle_ConnectMqttBroker could not connect to mqtts-up.iot.arduino.cc:8884
> ArduinoIoTCloudTCP::handle_ConnectMqttBroker 1 connection attempt at tick time 27850

This is my code:

```
#include "thingProperties.h"
#include "WiFiS3.h"
#include "Servo.h"
#include "Arduino_WiFiConnectionHandler.h"

char ssid[] = "ASK4 Wireless";

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiServer server(80);
Servo myservo;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1500);
  myservo.attach(7);

  //initProperties();
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();

  while (!Serial) {
    ;  // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  server.begin();
  // you're connected now, so print out the status:
  printWifiStatus();
  
  while (ArduinoCloud.connected() == false) {
    ArduinoCloud.update();
    delay(500);
  }
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //Serial.print("Test");
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  delay(2500);
}

void onFanChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon ExtractorFan change
  myservo.write(0);
  delay(1000);
  myservo.write(120);
}
```

This is my first proper project in years so any and all advice is appreciated.

(Just for context, I live in a building that uses ASK4 internet. For this service, you have to add the MAC address of the device to your account before it can connect. I have confirmed via the Monitor that it does connect to wifi but this error also comes up. I am able to add the device to my alexa account but nothing happens.)

TIA
:)

I've tried looking around the web and various forums. Nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from error encountered this has to do mostly with connection to mqtts using Arduino Uno R4 Wifi. And Tutorial below uses the ArduinoMqttClient and WiFiNINA libraries withuno-wifi-r2 to Send Data over MQTT and I'm hoping this might help achieve connection to Mqtts successfully:

- https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-wifi-rev2/uno-wifi-r2-mqtt-device-to-device

I noted you are able to add device via Arduino skill on Alexa app and therefore I suspect issue remains with properly establishing connection with mqtts broker and you might find more resources with regards to arduino and mqtts related concerns, configuration by checking out the [Arduino forum & documentation](https://forum.arduino.cc/latest) for similar concerns

As far as the Alexa side, I understand you are certainly using Arduino skill to discover device properly without being able to proceed and control device and this might resolved once mqtts connection error is addressed in your set up.